# Drag and drop the textview on imageview?

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, textview

can any one help me how to drag and drop the text view on entire image view. i found from this [drag n drop textview in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418255/drag-n-drop-textview-in-android) here the text view is static, in my app textview and image view's are dynamically change. `@Override
                public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

```
  switch (event.getAction()) {
     case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
         // Remember our initial down event location.
         startX = event.getRawX();
         startY = event.getRawY();
         break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
         float x = event.getRawX();
         float y = event.getRawY();
        // Calculate move update. This will happen many times
        // during the course of a single movement gesture.
        scrollByX = x - startX; //move update x increment
        scrollByY = y - startY; //move update y increment
        startX = x; //reset initial values to latest
        startY = y;
        invalidate(); //force a redraw
        break;
      }
   return true; //done with this event so consume it
 }
```

i wright this code, but it's not working properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always change the image and text of existing view programatically using setText sort of methods.

There are many drag and drop tutrials if you google it.  strongly suggest you try them out.
Basically what you do is implement a OnTouchListener on the TextView like

textview.setOntouchListener(listen);

```
OnTouchListener onThumbTouch = new OnTouchListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
        {   
            switch(v.getId())
            {
                case R.id.slider_thumb_id:
                {
                    switch(event.getAction())
                    {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        {                           


                        }
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        {                           

                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    };
```

Here from the event attribute you get the value of x and y and the touch event and
use that to alter the position of the textview. I did it by add add/subtracting the margin values.

EDIT:
This is what I did to update the position of my view
Look event.getRawY(); is going to give you the distance from the parent view. So if I get event.getRawY() = 50. I know I need the text view to be 50 pixels from the top.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams iconParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) 
   v.getLayoutParams();
iconParams.topMargin = 50;
v.setLayoutParams(iconParams);
```

So now the view that i selected is 50 px from the top of the parent view.

Comment: please send me that function.@blessenm

Comment: I used imageview.setMargin(). You won't need to invalidate.

Comment: Ive edited my answer. The above code goes inside the listener.

Comment: i tried this tv2.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod()); but it's not working.

Comment: see this link : http://dl.dropbox.com/u/38493970/device-2011-08-23-175817.png  i want move that WELCOME text on the entire Imaga.